# How can we write this big one in latex?

Tags: fonts, symbols, packages

I want to write this 1 in latex, could anyone help me, please?

> [image]

Comment: @Zarko Hi, the tags are all wrong. Can I edit the question of the user?

Comment: @Sebastiano yes, please. this is my first time to ask here so I do not understand exactly which tag my question should go under

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My welcome to TeX.SE. This is a standard question. The next time use this tool to search your symbol: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

$f \times \mathds{1}$
\end{document}
```

If you do not like the symbol 1 in the image, there is another option with LaTeX. Use `bbold` package as an example and image that I have included.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

$f \times \mathbb{1}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: why $\mathds{1}$ is not working when I am editing a question on math stack exchange?

Comment: @hopefully For my humble opinion LaTeX is not MathJaX :O)

Comment: So how can I type this symbol in MathJaX?

Comment: @hopefully There is not. Sorry. Can you read this link, please? https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/792

Comment: so what shall I do in this case?

Comment: @hopefully Math stack exchange works with MathJax, but MathJaX is not LaTeX...therefore...there is no possibility to have this symbol. Look this link https://www.mathjax.org/#demo and on live demo write: $\mathds{1}$. The \mathsds is colored in red.